# Go: polynomial fingerprint for string comparison

Tags: algorithm, go, math, hash, rabin-karp

I want to implement a rolling hash function to do string comparison (Rabin-Karp)

To do so, I convert my input string into a slice of bytes (using go unicode/utf8) and operate the "polynomial fingerprinting" function on it.

For instance, I input the string `qwerty` which translate to `[113 119 101 114 116 121]`

I use a base `256`

```
rune 121, base 256.0, exponent 0, value 121
rune 116, base 256.0, exponent 1, value 29696
rune 114, base 256.0, exponent 2, value 7471104
rune 101, base 256.0, exponent 3, value 1694498816
rune 119, base 256.0, exponent 4, value 511101108224
rune 113, base 256.0, exponent 5, value 124244813938688
```

I have troubles with the concept of 'polymonial fingerprint' : rapidly, the base gets really big how that could scale with the string input the user want to match ?

In my use case, it get messed up after 7 character because the Go `math.Pow` function uses float64 type

```
rune 114, base 256.0, exponent 7, value 8214565720323784704
rune 101, base 256.0, exponent 8, value -9223372036854775808
rune 119, base 256.0, exponent 9, value -9223372036854775808
rune 113, base 256.0, exponent 10, value -9223372036854775808
```

I feel using uint64 will just move a bit forward the issue

Comment: You probably want the [math/big](https://golang.org/pkg/math/big/) package to handle large numbers.

Comment: You should be taking the result modulo N for some N (if you're doing a simple rolling hash, rather than rabin fingerprinting). If you're using rabin fingerprinting, it's more difficult, but see: https://github.com/aclements/go-rabin/tree/master/rabin

Comment: `math.Pow` is not suitable for this, and you shouldn't need any pow function at all.

Comment: I should not need any pow function at all, you mean : just implement it ?
i am looking at exponentiation by square

Answer (score 1):

The idea of hash function is actually that it will overflow, but with high probability, different strings will give different hashes. In order to make it work, you need to use coprime numbers for the base and modulus of the operations. You should use some prime base (bigger than the alphabet size) and perform all operations modulus some prime number (as big as possible) (prime numbers will lead to minimal collision chance). Use integer type for this hash. If you need your alphabet to be at least 256 symbols, you can use uint64, base 257 and perform all operations, for example, modulus 10<sup>12</sup>+39